# JFileChooser for passing selected file into argument of different class object

Tags: java, netbeans

in my main class I have this method

```
private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new TxtFileFilter());
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    }

    }
```

I want to pass the selected file into the argument of an object in another class of the same project and package:

```
public class ImportFile {

    File fileToImport = new File("C:/data/myData.txt");//path will be set from GUI
```

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do someting like this:

```
private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new TxtFileFilter());
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        SomeClass c = new SomeClass(f);
        c.processFile();
    }

    }
```

Although it would be better to do the processing in another thread instead of the Event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your main class you should return the file F.

That way from any other class in the same package you can call the OpenActionPerformed() method and have it returned into a new File object in whatever class you use it from.

Comment: @user511202 I can't return anything since the method is declared private void